# Getting error when validation error in "422 (Unprocessable Entity)" Laravel7

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-7

I am using laravel 7 . Getting issue when update data. When i edit and update data its successfully updated but i validation error occurs then come error in console ""422 (Unprocessable Entity)" Laravel7" . I cant find out why this happen.
My script code as follows

```
    if ($("#productForm").length > 0) {
            $("#productForm").validate({
  
                submitHandler: function(form)
                 {
  
                      var actionType = $('#btn-save').val();
                      $('#btn-save').html('Sending..');
                       
                     $.ajax({
                              data: $('#productForm').serialize(),
                              
                              url:"contact-list/store",
                              type: "POST",
                              dataType: 'json',
                              success: function (data) {
                                console.log("dgfd");
                              $('#productForm').trigger("reset");
                              $('#user_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                              $('#ajax-product-modal').modal('hide');
                              $('#btn-save').html('Save Changes');
                              var oTable = $('#laravel_datatable').dataTable();
                              oTable.fnDraw(false);
               
                              },
                              error: function (data) {
                                console.log("data");
                                  console.log('Error:', data);
                                  $('#btn-save').html('Save Changes');
                              }
                            });
                    }
            })
        }

my controller :
   
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validate = $request->validate([
                        'name' => 'required',
                        'email' => 'email',
                        'phone' => 'digits:10',
                        'address' => 'required',
                        'country' => 'required',
                        'state' => 'required',
                        // 'comment' => 'required',
                        'organization' => 'required',
                        'captcha' => 'required|captcha'
                    ],
                    [
                        'captcha.captcha' => 'Incorrect Captcha'
                    ]
                );

        // if ($validate->fails())
        // {
        //     return response()->json(['errors'=>$validate->errors()->all()]);
        // }

        $id=$request->contact_id;

        $customer = CustomerContact::find($id);
        $customer->name = $request->name;
        $customer->email = $request->email;
        $customer->phone = $request->phone;
        $customer->address = $request->address;
        $customer->country_id = $request->country;
        $customer->state_id = $request->state;
        $customer->comment = $request->comment;
        $customer->organization = $request->organization;
        $customer->captcha = $request->captcha;

 
        $a=$customer->update();
        return Response::json($a);

    }

Nd modal 
 
    <div class="modal fade" id="ajax-product-modal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="productCrudModal"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        
        <form id="productForm" name="productForm" class="form-horizontal">
           
            @csrf
             <div class="form-header">
                <h4>Edit Employee Information</h4>
             </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="required">Your Name</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="contact_id" id="contact_id">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
                    <span class="error_message"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email Id</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email Id" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
                    <span class="error_message"></span>
            </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Please see attachment of console
[image]

In response getting proper validation message
[image]

Help me in this if anyone have idea.

Comment: seems like validation is failing

Comment: Are you already input the captcha?

Comment: It seems to be null on your input.

Comment: validation fails but ajax error response not getting error message in console.log(data). No not already put the captcha

Comment: the error seems to imply that the captcha field didn't make it

Comment: @legabox i m not getting you what you want say?

Comment: the error message is a validation error that is saying the `captcha` field is required, so it wasn't sent or is `null`

Comment: Yes right but in modal i want to show the error respective filed. But in error reponse i am not getting that one.

Comment: the error contains the field that failed `errors.captcha`

Comment: error: function (data) {
                                console.log("data");
                                console.log(data.errors.captcha);
                                  console.log('Error:', data);
                                  $('#btn-save').html('Save Changes');
                              }

Comment: I am doing this but not getting anything in console

Answer (score 0):

```
data: $('#productForm').serialize(),
```

Here is data you send to Server, and I guess data of you not have capcha value, So now we have 2 solution:

1: You need to remove `captcha` in validate of Controller

2: Add captcha value to data when make request to server

But I think you should choose options 1, because captcha should be check on client, Don't need in server check

Comment: I dont Want update data without captcha value? I want to add validation empty and match captcha.

Comment: Okay, So when you submit you show error to user like server return

Comment: Yes right. If captcha (any other field) empty then show error "Captcha not empty"